# How to cut/copy/paste text to JTextField when some JComponent is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcomponent, jwindow

I'm creating custom popup menu, using just extended `JComponent` as a menu items and extended `JWindow` to hold them. My question is - how to send signal from `JComponent` instance when it's clicked (has `MouseListener`) to `JTextField` to perform cut/copy/paste actions?

**EDIT:**

I will try to explain more precisely.

JTextField class (simplified):

```
public class TextInputField extends JTextField implements FocusListener {

        private MenuPopupWindow popUp;

        public TextInputField() {


           popUp = new MenuPopupWindow();//MenuPopupWindow class extends JWindow

           MenuItem paste = new MenuItem("Paste", 
                                         new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/paste_icon.png")),
                                         "Ctrl+V");//MenuItem class extends JComponent, has implemented MouseListener - and when mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) occurs, somehow action signal have to be sent to this class
            MenuItem copy = ....
            MenuItem cut = ....


            Action pasteAction = getActionMap().get(DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction);
            paste.setAction(pasteAction);//How to make it to work?


            popUp.addMenuItem(paste);
            popUp.addMenuItem(cut);
            popUp.addMenuItem(copy);

        }
        }
```

How to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In light of your posted code, I think all you need to do in your TextInputField class, is add:

```
paste.addActionListener(pasteAction);
```

then in your MenuItem class you have to put in code to call those action listeners.

```
public class MenuItem implements MouseListener
{
    ...
    @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
    {
        ActionListener[] listeners = (ActionListener[])
            MenuItem.this.getListeners(ActionListener.class);
        for(int i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++)
        {
            listeners[i].actionPerformed
            (
                new ActionEvent(MenuItem.this,someID, someCMDName)
            );
        }
    }
```

In your class that extends JComponent (I'll call it class 'A') you will need to get a reference to your JTextField. A simple way to do this is to add a private instance variable of type JTextField to class A, and pass in the JTextField through the constructor.

so your class should look something like this:

```
public class A extends JComponent implements ActionListener
{
    private JTextField updateField;

    public A(JTextField updateField[,<your other contructor arguments>...])
    {
        this.updateField = updateField;
        this.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getSource().equals(this)
        {
            //copy, paste or do whatever with the JTextField
            //by way of this.updateField;
            //e.g. this.updateField.setText(...);
            //or to simply pass the event along to the JTextField's handlers
            //this.updateField.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

then you just have to remember to pass the jtextField into the constructor when you create your component

Comment: This is closer, but hmm.. I have implemented MouseListener in MenuItem, also Action is passed from TextInputField class. Do I need also implement ActionListener in MenuItem? It would be nice to use only MouseListener.

Comment: I have tried this in MenuItem class: `textField.dispatchEvent(new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction));` - but it's not working also.

Comment: oh, if you haven't done it already, you will need to call the action listeners in the menu item class from the mouse handlers. Ill edit again with a way to do that.

Comment: Thanks indeed for help, finally solved this problem - just made: `public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        invoker.dispatchEvent(e);
    }` at MenuItem class, and added MouseListener in TextInputField class, then `Object obj = e.getSource();
                if (obj instanceof MenuItem) {
                    if (paste == (MenuItem) obj) {
                        paste();
                    }
                    .....
                }` - now everything works super :)

Comment: glad it worked, please accept the answer or post your  own so that the site will mark it solved

Comment: So now I have even 2 ways how to do that :) But I think to post MouseEvent from MenuItem in this case is simpler. Thanks Aaron indeed.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm creating custom popup menu, using just extended JComponent as a menu items and extended JWindow to hold them.

Not really sure what all that means.

You should just use a JPopupMenu and add JMenuItems to it. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for an example.

Then, if you want cut/copy/paste functionality, you can use the default actions provided by the DefaultEditorKit:

```
popup.add( new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction()) );
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is to simple for me, I have a goal to create my own Popup menu - which is already done, just need somehow to pass Action / ActionEvent to JTextField.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work (sorry, haven't had time to test), but from reading the source, the `actionPerformed` method (basically) does `((JTextComponent)actionEvent.getSource())` to get the `JTextComponent` from the event source...which would be, in this case, the `JMenuItem`....

Answer (score 0):

So my working example follows (simplified):

```
    public class TextInputField extends JTextField {

    private MenuPopupWindow popUp;
    private MenuItem copy,
            cut,
            paste,
            selectAll;

    public TextInputField() {

        popUp = new MenuPopupWindow();

        paste = new MenuItem(this, "Paste", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Paste-icon.png")), "Ctrl+V");
        cut = new MenuItem(this, "Cut", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Cut-icon.png")), "Ctrl+X");
        copy = new MenuItem(this, "Copy", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Copy-icon.png")), "Ctrl+C");
        selectAll = new MenuItem(this, "Select All", null, "Ctrl+A");

        popUp.addMenuItem(paste);
        popUp.addMenuItem(cut);
        popUp.addMenuItem(copy);
        popUp.addMenuItem(selectAll);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {

                    if (getSelectedText() == null) {
                        copy.setEnabled(false);
                        cut.setEnabled(false);
                    } else {
                        copy.setEnabled(true);
                        cut.setEnabled(true);
                    }

                    if (getText().equals("")) {
                        selectAll.setEnabled(false);
                    } else {
                        selectAll.setEnabled(true);
                    }

                    Clipboard c = getToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

                    Transferable t = c.getContents(this);

                    if (t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {

                        String s;

                        try {
                            s = (String) t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                            if (s.equals("")) {
                                paste.setEnabled(false);
                            } else {
                                paste.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(TextInputField.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }

                    } else {
                        paste.setEnabled(false);
                    }

                    popUp.setLocation(e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen());
                    getCaret().setVisible(false);
                    popUp.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    Object obj = e.getSource();
                    if (obj instanceof MenuItem) {
                        MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) obj;
                        if (paste == menuItem) {
                            paste();
                        } else if (cut == menuItem) {
                            cut();
                        } else if (copy == menuItem) {
                            copy();
                        } else if (selectAll == menuItem) {
                            selectAll();
                        }
                    }

                    getCaret().setVisible(true);
                    popUp.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
   }
}
```

And at MenuItem class added (simplified):

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    textField.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

Works superb :)

Decided to use Component instead of JComponent in MenuItem class, because there is no need for paintComponent, paintBorder and paintChildren constructors - saving resources.